# Calling Unmanaged Code from C# and Checking Returned Value with Known Constants

Tags: c#, .net, unmanaged

In a DLL for target platform .NET 3.5 written in C#, I'm going to use [CMP_WaitNoPendingInstallEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff537916%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) unmanaged function. As described in the documentation, this method returns `WAIT_OBJECT_0`, `WAIT_TIMEOUT` and `WAIT_FAILED` values which are defined in **winbase.h** file. I need to check this return value from C# and take action.

How can I compare the returned value with the constants defined in **winbase.h** from C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in winnt.h

```
#define STATUS_WAIT_0       ((DWORD)0x00000000L)
```

in winbase.h

```
#define WAIT_OBJECT_0       ((STATUS_WAIT_0 ) + 0 )
#define WAIT_FAILED         ((DWORD)0xFFFFFFFF)
```

and in winerror.h

```
#define WAIT_TIMEOUT        258L    // dderror
```

You should define these constants yourself. To use the constants in windows header files directly, you could implement a C++ static library to return their values, but this is no use since it will produce the same result becuase the constant values will be inlined anyway.

```
[DllImport("cfgmgr32.dll", SetLastError = true, EntryPoint = "CMP_WaitNoPendingInstallEvents", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern uint CMP_WaitNoPendingInstallEvents(uint TimeOut);

private const uint WAIT_OBJECT_0 = 0x0;
private const uint WAIT_TIMEOUT = 0x102;
private const uint WAIT_FAILED = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

Then should PInvoke:

```
uint result = CMP_WaitNoPendingInstallEvents(1000);
switch (result)
{
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        break;
    case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
        break;
    case WAIT_FAILED:
        break;
}
```